# Links don't work on mobile due to Javascript hover effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

On [my site](http://sophiecalhoun.com) I've used [hover.css](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/) to add a hover animation to my nav links. For some reason, this is causing the links to not be clickable on mobile. Any ideas on how to resolve this? Here's some of my code:
Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sss.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sss2.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="sss.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$('.slider').sss();
});
</script>
<div class="links">
<center>

<h>&nbsp;Sophie Calhoun </h>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="http://www.sophiecalhoun.com/" class="hvr-grow"> &nbsp;home&nbsp; </a>&nbsp; 
<a href="http://www.sophiecalhoun.com/design.html" class="hvr-grow"> &nbsp;design work&nbsp; </a>&nbsp; 
<!-- <a href="http://www.sophiecalhoun.com/illustration.html" > &nbsp;illustration </a><p> &nbsp;<p> --!>
<a href="http://www.sophiecalhoun.com/motion.html" class="hvr-grow"> &nbsp;motion graphics&nbsp; </a> &nbsp;
<a href="http://www.sophiecalhoun.com/interactive.html" class="hvr-grow"> &nbsp;interactive&nbsp; </a>&nbsp; 
<a href="http://www.sophiecalhoun.com/resume.html" class="hvr-grow"> &nbsp;resume&nbsp; </a>  &nbsp; &nbsp;</center></div></div>
<!--etc.--!>
```

And here's the CSS modifying the hvr-grow property:

```
.hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-grow:hover, .hvr-grow:focus, .hvr-grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

I'd like to know if I can disable this effect on mobile or somehow make the links work with the effect. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing a user agent test to detect mobile browsers.

Check out this site:
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Or do something like this:

```
if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i)) {
 $('.hvr-grow').removeClass('hvr-grow');
}
```

Use .hvr-grow only for animations so you don't have the issue with the links dissappearing, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.sophiecalhoun.com/" class="hvr-grow links"> &nbsp;home&nbsp; </a>&nbsp; 
<a href="http://www.sophiecalhoun.com/design.html" class="hvr-grow links"> &nbsp;design work&nbsp; </a>&nbsp; 

.links {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.hvr-grow {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-grow:hover, .hvr-grow:focus, .hvr-grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

good luck!

Comment: Thanks--do you have any code to recommend to remove the class from the elements?

Comment: $('.hvr-grow').removeClass("hvr-grow");

Comment: did you add the "links" class to the a elements?

Comment: also i would suggest putting the script at the end of the page. and wrapping it in $(document).ready(function() {}); so that the dom is loaded before removing the classes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test your css on a mobile device right now, but if you just wanted to disable the effect, you could wrap the css in a media query so that it is only used on larger screen sizes.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    /* Your css here */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that but it just makes the links completely vanish.

Comment: @Ishyla Right, only put the css for the transition within the media query. Your basic link css should be outside so that it is always used.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did, but it still entirely removes the links--I guess it has something to do with the fact that they're assigned the class .hvr-grow within the HTML.